# Classifying a PDE as elliptic iff $b^2 (x,y) - a(x,y)c(x,y) < 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification

A second order PDE can be expressed in the form
$$ F(D^{2}u , Du ,u , x) = 0.$$
if $F$ is linear in $D^{2}u$ then we can express
$$ F(D^{2}u , Du , u ,x) = L [u] + G(Du, u ,x),\tag{1}$$
with
$$ L[u] := -\text{tr}(A(x)D^{2}u),\tag{2}$$
for which $A(x)$ is a symmetric $n\times n $ matrix.

#### Problem statement

Let $u \in C^2 (\mathbb{R}^2)$ , with $u=u(x,y)$. Consider
$$ L[u] = a(x,y)u_{xx} + 2b(x,y)u_{xy} + c(x,y)u_{yy}.$$
By definition we consider a PDE to be elliptic if for every $x$ , $A(x) = A_{ij}(x)$ has nonzero eigenvalues all of the same sign.

Show why the following definition is equivalent to that above :
$$\text{(i)} \ L[u] \ \text{is elliptic iff } b^2(x,y) - a(x,y)c(x,y) < 0. \tag{3}$$

#### Attempt at solution

From $(2)$ we deduce $A(x)$ to be $A(x) =  \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ b& c \end{bmatrix}$, i.e.
\begin{align} au_{xx} + 2bu_{xy} + cu_{yy} &= \text{tr}\left( \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ b& c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u_{xx} & u_{xy} \\ u_{yx} & u_{yy}\end{bmatrix}\right). \\
\end{align}
We then look for the eigenvalues of $A$:
\begin{align}
 (a-\lambda)(c-\lambda) - b^2 = 0 &\implies ac - \lambda(a+c) + \lambda^2 -b^2 =0 \\
&\implies \lambda^2 -\lambda(c+a) + ac-b^2 =0 \\
&\implies \lambda = \frac{(c+a) \pm \sqrt{(c+a)^2 +4(b^2 -ac)}}{2}
\end{align}

From here, if $(b^2 - ac)<0 \implies 4(b^2 -ac) < 0$. But only if I make the assumption that $(c+a)^2 > \lvert 4(b^2 -ac)\rvert$ the condition $(3)$ hold (i.e., both $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$ are nonzero and of the same sign), and I don't understand how I can justify this assumption. If the discriminant $\Delta < 0 \implies \lambda$ is imaginary, what would that imply in light of the condition $(3)$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to make any such assumption. Since $A$ is symmetric, the eigenvalues are real, so the number under the squareroot must be non-negative. Indeed, if you just expand the brackets, you can see this:

\begin{align}(c+a)^2+4(b^2-ac) 
&= c^2 + a^2 + 2ac - 4ac +4b^2 
\\
&= c^2 + a^2 - 2ac + 4b^2
\\
&= (a-c)^2 +4b^2 
\\
&\ge 0.\end{align}

A shorter solution:

You have identified the matrix $A$. Its determinant is $ac-b^2$ and also the product of the eigenvalues $ac-b^2=\lambda_1\lambda_2$. Therefore this has a positive  sign for all $x$ iff the eigenvalues are always of the same sign.

Comment: Wow , ok thank you this is really nice solution ! I'm wondering though, is the approach that I provided also a viable solution? Or where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: @hitechphysics I added an explanation for your proof as well